# I am stuck at fetching categorized posts via mongodb in nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

***I am stuck at fetching categorized posts via mongodb in nextjs app***

I have 2 Models One is Post Model and other one is Category Model. I want to make a relation between Post Model and Category Model in such a way that Each Category Should fetch only its relevant Posts.

***POST MODEL***

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const postSchema = new Schema({
    createdAt : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
      },
    slug : {type: String, unique:true},
    title:     String,
    desc:      String,
    img:       String,
    views:     {type:Number,       default:0},
    catSlug:   String,
    

    ***cat:       [{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Category'}],*** ====> I have tried to connect it but it is not working.

    userEmail: String,
    user: [{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}],
    tags: [String]
})



const Post = mongoose.models.Post ||mongoose.model("Post", postSchema )

export default Post
```

***CATEGORY MODEL***

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose"

const categorySchema = new Schema({
    title: {type:String, required:true},
    slug:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    Posts:[{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Post'}]
},

{timestamps:true}

)


const Category = mongoose.models.Category ||mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema )

export default Category
```

***ROUTE FOR FETCHING DATA***

```
import Post from "@/app/models/Post"
import ConnectDB from "@/utils/ConnectDB"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export const GET = async (req) => {
    const {searchParams} = new URL(req.url)
    const cat = searchParams.get("cat")
    
    try {
        await ConnectDB()
    
        const posts = await Post.find({ cat }).populate('cat')
        return NextResponse.json({posts},{status:200})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return NextResponse.json({"Msg":"Error fetching Posts by Cat"},{status:500})
        
    }
}
```

After fetching i got the following error:

"CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Travel" (type string) at path "cat" for model "Post"

In above Error "Travel" refers to the Category Name i am fetching.

It is probably the problem with Post.find() method.

I am following a tutorial in which the tutor uses prisma but i an not good at prisma either therefore i wanted to do it with MongoDB and React. The Prisma Models are as under:-

```
model Category {
  slug  String  @unique
  title String
  Posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  slug      String    @unique
  title     String
  desc      String
  img       String?
  views     Int       @default(0)
  catSlug   String
  cat       Category  @relation(fields: [catSlug], references: [slug])
  userEmail String
  user      User      @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple match query solved my problem:

```
  const posts = await Post.aggregate(
        [ { $match : { catSlug : cat } } ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a query problem.

`const posts = await Post.find({ cat }).populate('cat')`
This will search for { cat: 'Travel' }, which won't work as mongodb expects an ObjectId, to search for 'Travel', you should either query Category directly and populate posts from there.

`const categories = await Category.find({ title: 'Travel'}).populate('Post')`

or if you want to query as you have done above then you will need the querying options like `match` which will match the title of category to what you have searched. you can reference [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)